# Best masters degree in data science and engineering in Europe

Tags: data

I have a BSc in Applied Mathematics and I was thinking about an MSc in Data Science or Data Engineering, but I have no ideia what are the best programs available in Europe.
Any suggestions of good universities with MSc's in this field?

Comment: Yes i am willing to pay